# Creating Table in AWS Redshift with AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a temporary table inside of AWS redshift using the java SDK.

```
 // Redshift JDBC 4.1 driver: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver
 String command = "CREATE TABLE test (FirstName varchar(255));"
 Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver");
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, props);
 stmt = conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(command);
```

When running this code the table is created successfully but on the return, an error is thrown

```
com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSISimpleRowCountResult cannot be cast to com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.interfaces.IResultSet
```

Everything will work if I use a command that returns something, such as

```
"Select * FROM test;" 
"SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 0;"
```

I didn't see any documentation for this problem in the AWS READMEs or other stack overflow questions for this problem. It seems to me that there is a special class in the driver for when nothing is returned from the statement that is not able to be cast to the ResultSet class.

The redshift driver version is 1.1.13.1013 .

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had  the same problem. You can solve this easily. Instead of

```
stmt.executeQuery(command);
```

please try

```
stmt.execute(command);
```